# Calling JavaScript directly from TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have just downloaded the TypeScript documentation. I have a some JavaScript classes and I would like to create and use these class in a TypeScript test application

How can I call a JavaScript function of an included JavaScript from TypeScript. I do not want to create a "d.ts" file. Just to create my classes, call its methods, access its properties.

How do I do that?

---

I am trying to use kendoUI with TypeScript.

For instance to show a window I have to do:

1. Have a HTML to represent the content of a window. I have a div with an id logonDialog. This div
   is initially hidden;
2. I create the window: logonDlg.kendoWindow(logOnParams);
3. Then using jQuery I show the div: using `logonDlg.show();`

Example

```
var logonDlg = $("logonDialog");

if (!logonDlg.data("kendoWindow")) {
   logonDlg.kendoWindow(logOnParams);
   logonDlg.show();
}
```

It is working OK. The JS is generated as I want but I receive an error since The property 'kendoWindow' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'.

How can I disable this kind of error. I could not make, what Ryan said, to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just do it. TypeScript won't stop you. You will see warnings in the compiler output but `tsc` will generate your JS file just fine.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I will try it soon.

Comment: this is not the case in vs2013? Building stops and i can not run my project.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to stop the errors without doing much else extra work, you can 'declare' the objects from your JS code:

```
declare var w; // implicit type here is 'any'
// (later, anywhere in your file...)
var x = new w(); // you can do whatever you want with w now without getting errors
w.x = 4; // etc.
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a better solution. Just cast the jQuery logonDlg to any like this:

```
(<any>logonDlg).kendoWindow(logOnParams);
```

The code will be a bit different but will work the same.

1. Without the cast th generated code is like this: **logonDlg.kendoWindow(logOnParams);**
2. With the cast will be like this: **(logonDlg).kendoWindow(logOnParams);**

Both work OK.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case you could just include the [Kendo UI TypeScript definitions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/typescript) that Telerik provides.

*(I realize this question was asked back when the TS definitions probably didn't exist yet, but wanted to add this detail for people who come across this question in the future.)*