# Angular2 with Material Design Lite

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, material-design-lite

I have added the following bit of code in my angular2 app to help MDL re-register the components when moving around the app...

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
}
```

And although it seems to be working ok (as expected) I am getting the following error...

```
(16,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'componentHandler'.
```

I'm still quite new to angular2 and typescript but I guess I need to import something so my code knows what componentHandler is(even though it must know what it is because it works and doesn't work without this code??? confused)

Comment: Anybody looking at this in the future and having issues that involve routed components might want to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162649/angular2-router-interacting-with-material-design-lite/36163652#36163652).  There are some subtleties when dealing with routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should help you to add

```
declare var componentHandler: any;
```

at the top of your code. Please refer to the corresponding [handbook section](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries) on *Working with Other JavaScript Libraries* in TypeScript.

Comment: I am getting  ReferenceError: componentHandler is not defined .. I'm not sure why.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using cli.angular tool for generating your app
do this, so that no need to duplicate the code everywhere.

1. add below line into typings.d.ts file

   ```
      declare var componentHandler: any;
   ```
2. reference the file into your component file as below

   ```
      /// <reference path="../typings.d.ts" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add

```
declare componentHandler;
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

See also [Calling JavaScript directly from TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710962/calling-javascript-directly-from-typescript)