# Angular2 Router interacting with Material Design Lite

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I've come across an interaction between the Angular2 router and the Material Design Lite (MDL) animations.  If I create an `<input>` element in a component that is rendered by the `<router-outlet>` component in Angular2, MDL doesn't properly handle my interactions with it (doesn't show focus animation, doesn't clear placeholder text, etc).  If, on the other hand, the `<input>` appears outside the `<router-outlet>`, there is no problem.

It seems like it has something to do with the dynamic nature of the contents of `<router-outlet>`.  I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339570/angular2-with-material-design-lite) would solve the issue.  I added an `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterViewChecked` handler to my application (and even to my custom directive that extends `RouterOutlet`).  No luck.  I can see the `componentHandler` variable and call the `updateDom` method...no problem.  But it has no effect.

There must be some way to get MDL to "see" these dynamically created elements, but my attempts with `upgradeDom` haven't been working.  Maybe `upgradeDom` isn't the problem...but then what is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So after further digging, I thought I had found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2).  Playing with the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dtaQhAI7k7r5q7js6CSB?p=preview) I was able to show that the right manual call to `componentHandler.<something>` could address a similar issue I had managed to contrive in that plunkr.

However, the approach there (of creating a custom directive that triggered those calls on lifecycle events that the directive was attached to) didn't solve my issue.  The "dynamic" nature of the `router-outlet` was still interfering.  As far as I can tell, the calls to `componentHandler` were still premature and being done before the DOM had truly been updated by the `router-outlet`.

What I eventually had to do was to add some code to the `activate` method of `RouterOutlet`.  I was already creating a custom `RouterOutlet` class, so it was simple enough to stick the code in the `activate` method.

However, I found that is is **essential** that you wait until the `Promise` associated with the `activate` method is resolved.  So I did something like this:

```
declare var componentHandler: any;

...
export class MyRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  ...
  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    // My custom activate stuff (i.e., check that user is
    // authorized to view this content)

    // Important part, call base class...
    return super.activate(instruction)
       .then((x) => {
          componentHandler.upgradeDom();
          return x;
       });
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I have not confirmed it, but I suspect that the reason the other solutions I alluded to did not work was because of [another issue I ran across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338606/angular2-router-and-oninit/36338761).  My suspicion is that addressing that issue properly would have allowed the other solutions I referenced here to work.