# Angular2 Router and OnInit

Tags: angular, router

I recently started having difficulty with the Angular2 router.  The issue was that components that were outside the `router-outlet` would have their `ngOnInit` methods called.  But components that were inside the `router-outlet` would not.

I'd had [previous issues with the Angular2 router as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162649/angular2-router-interacting-with-material-design-lite).  But that issue seemed to be related to external Javascript code whereas this one seemed to be clearly an issue with the Angular2 lifecycle hooks.

I put together some Plunker's but couldn't reproduce the issues.  So that is the problem.  It turns out, I figured out what the issue was (and it was hinted at in some other things I'd read).  So I'm posting this as a question and I'll include what I found as an answer in case anybody else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned before, I'd see other issues with the Angular2 router.  Now that I've dug into this more, I think they are related.

I'm bucking the trend here a little and not using SystemJS.  Instead, I'm just doing a simple webpack build.  That seems to be where the issue lies.  I'd seen a few other issues and stackoverflow questions where they mentioned the importance of the order of `script` tags.  Well, since `webpack` takes direct control of such things away from me, I didn't really pay attention.  But it turns out it is important.

I'm currently producing a `bundle.js` file from `webpack`.  But what I didn't appreciate is that you also have to find a way to include the `angular2-polyfills.js` in your application.  I kind of assumed it would somehow get included by `webpack` somehow, but it doesn't.

The first thing I tried was to simply add it into the `<head>` section of my index.html.  This loads it outside of `webpack`, and that seems to be sufficient.  I also found that I could just include by adding:

```
require('angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills');
```

...in my webpack entrypoint.

Once the [`angular2-polyfills.js`](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2-polyfills.js) file was in place, the lifecycle hooks were getting properly called.