# How to add external javascript library in a gateway project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jhipster

I'm trying to add  [Simpl5](https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/sipml5/blob/master/SIPml.js) javascript library to my gateway unsuccessfully.
I've put **SIPml-api.js** and **SIPml.js** in **webapp/content/scripts** folder.

In **.angular-cli.json** I've update scripts array like this :

```
    "scripts": [
        "content/scripts/SIPml-api.js",
        "content/scripts/SIPml.js"
    ]
```

I've then try to call SIPml in component like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var SIPml: any;
```

.

```
ngOnInit() {
    SIPml.setDebugLevel((window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem('org.doubango.expert.disable_debug') === 'true') ? 'error' : 'info');

}
```

I getting **ERROR ReferenceError: SIPml is not defined** in the console.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: i think your function should be called `AfterViewInit`

Comment: .angular-cli.json is not used by JHipster webpack's configuration. Have you tried copying SIPml*.js to webapp/app folder and then follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318542/how-to-use-javascript-in-typescript

Comment: I've try to copy SIPml*.js to webapp/app but I'm still having SIPml is not defined. I've also added   "allowJs": true to tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JHipster` does not fully supports angular cli as @GaëlMarziou already mentioned in comments.

> The original idea of supporting the CLI was only for code generation.

So any `.angular-cli.json` modificatons won't have any effect as `JHipster` is using its own `build/serve` chain (have a look in to `package.json` custom scripts, they are not based on `ng serve/build`, etc ) check [this issue discussion](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6050) for more details.

You need to reference your custom `css` and `js` in `vendor.ts` then when you run `npm run serve` you will see the result.

Comment: I read the discussions but  I still can figure out how to do it.

Comment: @freemanpolys just updated the answer. Sorry the discussion didn't meant to be to show how to import custom assets, it was more about why angular cli is not fully supported.

Comment: Thanks @Kuncevic, vendor.ts is where to include external css and js.