# ERROR TypeError: $(...).FlowPaperViewer is not a function in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, blob, flexpaper

I am trying to use FlowPaper Viewer from my Angular 4 app. but I get the following error :

> core.es5.js?de3d:1020 ERROR TypeError: $(...).FlowPaperViewer is not a function

- Can anyone please help me to figure out the problem or give me an alternative solution where I can display the pdf from blob?
- Or can suggests me any other pdf viewer (better reader with nice look and feel) where I can display pdf from blob?

I tried as following (in Jhipster Angular 4 app): 
I have included the JS and CSS files manually in my project folder like:

```
webapp/content/css/flowpaper.css
webapp/content/js/jquery.min.js
webapp/content/js/jquery.extensions.min.js
webapp/content/js/fpsmeter.min.js
webapp/content/js/three.min.js
webapp/content/js/flowpaper.js
webapp/content/js/flowpaper_handlers.js
webapp/content/js/FlowPaperViewer.js
webapp/content/js/flowpaper.worker.js
```

then add the reference in the angular-cli.json file as following:

```
        "styles": [
            "content/css/vendor.css",
            "content/css/global.css",
            "content/css/flowpaper.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
            "content/js/jquery.min.js",
            "content/js/jquery.extensions.min.js",
            "content/js/fpsmeter.min.js",
            "content/js/three.min.js",
            "content/js/flowpaper.js",
            "content/js/flowpaper_handlers.js",
            "content/js/FlowPaperViewer.js",
            "content/js/flowpaper.worker.js"
        ]
```

In the Html file added :

```
<div id="documentViewer" class="flowpaper_viewer" style="position:absolute;;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#222222;;"></div>
```

in the component I declare jquery variable:

```
declare var $:any;
```

on receive pdf blob file I called :

```
uint8Array  = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
$('#documentViewer').FlowPaperViewer(
                        { config : {
                            PDFFile : uint8Array
                        }});
```

and I see in the chrome console :

> core.es5.js?de3d:1020 ERROR TypeError: $(...).FlowPaperViewer is not a function

Comment: DId you restart ng serve after modifying `angular.json` file?

Comment: @David yes! I did but faced the same issue.

Comment: Check the negerated bundles and see if you can see FlowPaper Viewer code in it

Comment: after following the link below finally found the code in the generated bundle. And the problem was related to JHipster project. I had to include the file in “vendor.ts’ file.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898654/how-to-add-external-javascript-library-in-a-gateway-project

but now another problem arises if I add : <div id="documentViewer" .... ></div>

if I remove the above tag, no problem. 

Error in console: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at DOMEval (jquery.js?eedf:82)
    ..