# Calling Javascript functions from typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 files, one named MIDI.js and another named app.ts. The first is in `javascript` the second in `typescript`.

Inside my app.ts i'd like to call the functions that are defined in MIDI.js. I've attempted to add

```
/// <reference path="MIDI.js"/>
```

to my typescript file but it says it won't import non-typescript files. I rename MIDI.ts but then Visual studio attempts to compile MIDI.js and spews out all sorts of errors.

I've searched everywhere on how to solve such a simple scenario but found no straightforward answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling JavaScript directly from TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710962/calling-javascript-directly-from-typescript)